# JUnit5 tag-specific gradle task

Tags: gradle, junit5

I use the following annotation to tag my integration tests:

```java
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Tag("integration-test")
public @interface IntegrationTest {
}
```

This is the filter I use in `build.gradle` to exclude these tests from `gradle build`:

```groovy
junitPlatform {
    filters {
        tags {
            exclude 'integration-test'
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good.

Now I would like to offer a Gradle task which specifically runs my integration tests – what's the recommended approach?

Comment: That's a very good question, and I'm afraid there is no _clean_ solution for achieving that at the moment due to how we have implemented the JUnit Platform Gradle plugin. Would you therefore be willing to create an issue so that we keep this on our radar? https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/579

Answer (score 68):

Based on https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6172#issuecomment-409883128

*Amended in 2020 to take lazy task configuration and Gradle 5 into account. See answer's history for older versions.*

```groovy
plugins {
    id "java"
}

def test = tasks.named("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags "integration"
    }
}

def integrationTest = tasks.register("integrationTest2", Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags "integration"
    }
    shouldRunAfter test
}

tasks.named("check") {
    dependsOn integrationTest
}
```

#### Running

- `gradlew test` will run tests without integration
- `gradlew integrationTest` will run only integration test
- `gradlew check` will run `test` followed by `integrationTest`
- `gradlew integrationTest test` will run `test` followed by `integrationTest`
  note: order is swapped because of `shouldRunAfter`

#### History

- Gradle 4.6+ supports JUnit 5 natively
- JUnit 5 deprecated their plugin: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1317
- JUnit 5 deleted `plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'`
- JUnit 5 closed [junit5#579 (same as OP's question)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/579) as won't-fix (due to decommissioning their plugin)
- Gradle supports the above feature: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6172

#### Tip

*Note: while the above works, IntelliJ IDEA has a hard time inferring stuff, so I suggest to use this more explicit version where everything is typed and code completion is fully supported*:

```groovy
... { Test task ->
    task.useJUnitPlatform { org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformOptions options ->
        options.includeTags 'integration'
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle.kts

Root project Kotlin DSL drop-in for configuring integration tests in all modules in Gradle 5.6.4

```kotlin
allprojects {
    plugins.withId("java") {
        @Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
        this@allprojects.tasks {
            val test = "test"(Test::class) {
                useJUnitPlatform {
                    excludeTags("integration")
                }
            }
            val integrationTest = register<Test>("integrationTest") {
                useJUnitPlatform {
                    includeTags("integration")
                }
                shouldRunAfter(test)
            }
            "check" {
                dependsOn(integrationTest)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

### Gradle 6

I am not sure if it is because Gradle behavior has changed, but the highest voted answer did not work for me in Gradle. 6.8.3. I was seeing the integrationTests task run along with the main test task. This simplified version worked for me:

```java
test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags "integration"
    }
}

tasks.register("integrationTests", Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags "integration"
    }
    mustRunAfter check
}
```

Commands:

- `./gradlew test` or `./gradlew clean build` - Runs tests *without*
  'integration' tag.
- `./gradlew integrationTests` - Only runs test *with*
  'integration' tag.

Comment: Completely agree. Highly voted answer didnt work for me but tagging is a great idea. It works well.

Answer (score 12):

I filed an issue: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/579 (as suggested by [Sam Brannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388980/sam-brannen)).

Meanwhile, I am using a project property as a workaround:

```groovy
junitPlatform {
    filters {
        tags {
            exclude project.hasProperty('runIntegrationTests') ? '' : 'integration-test'
        }
    }
}
```

Consequently, integrations tests will be *skipped* with:

`gradle test`

but will be *included* with:

`gradle test -PrunIntegrationTests`

Comment: Awesome! I was going to suggest a workaround similar to that. So I'm glad you figured it out on your own. Also, thanks for  raising the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to [Rahel Lüthy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57448/rahel-l%C3%BCthy) avoiding the usage of empty strings, in this case to run all tests or just some tags:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform() {
        if (project.hasProperty("includes")) {
            includeTags(project.property("includes") as String)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the best, current working code to solve this, is the one presented by: TWiStErRob found [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6172).

Note that tests must be tagged with ui in the example below ([Junit5 tagging](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit-5-tag-annotation-example/)):

```
task uiTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'ui'
        excludeTags 'integration'
    }
}
```

**Howe ever, I did not managed** to get the J[unit5 test-suit-thing](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit5-test-suites-examples/) to be run from gradle directly witch I would think would be an even nicer solution. But I think the solution buy TWiStErRob, is good enough. The down side is that the gradle.build file now also will be bloated with test-suit-things.

Please note that it is fine to create multiple test suites in the gradle file like this:

```
task firstTestSuite(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'test-for-first-test-suite'
    }
}

task secondTestSuite(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'test-for-second-test-suite'
    }
}
```

Then then all could be run separately like this:

```
gradlew firstTestSuite
gradlew secondTestSuite
gradlew ui
```

Solution run with Gradle 6.6.1

Comment: on gradle 8.4 this is failing with: `Could not find method useJUnitJupiter() for arguments [build_ar3rl6bhq28z99ils8w8dcamm$_run_closure9$_closure31$_closure32$_closure33@6203f258] on object of type org.gradle.api.plugins.jvm.internal.DefaultJvmTestSuite`

Comment: Mistake is mine: you are using `useJUnitPlatform()`, I am using `useJunitJupiter()`