# Exclude Nested Test Class with Gradle and JUnit 5

Tags: gradle, kotlin, junit5

I have a few nested classes using Kotlin and JUnit 5

```
class SomeTest {
    // test cases

    @Nested
    inner class SpecificTest {
        // test cases
    }

    @Nested
    inner class AnotherSpecificTest {
        // test cases
    }
}
```

I am attempting to exclude a few of the nested test classes when building with gradle (6.1.1).

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    exclude '**/SomeTest.class'
}
```

The above will ignore the entire test class, but I am only interested in excluding select nested test classes.

I've tried everything below, nothing seems to work.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    exclude '**/*SpecificTest*'
    exclude '**/$SpecificTest.class'
    exclude '**/*$SpecificTest.class'
    exclude '**/*$SpecificTest*'
    exclude '**/*$*SpecificTest*'
}
```

Does gradle support this functionality with JUnit 5? If so, how can it be accomplished?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `inner` modifier? Your classes are inner, not nested.

Comment: Only non-static nested classes can serve as @Nested test classes. Removing inner will violate this.

Comment: Alternatively you could use tags on the nested classes and exclude those.

Comment: Tags work. For anyone wanting to learn more on tags and gradle, this was very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891867/junit5-tag-specific-gradle-task/52245028#52245028